# How do I send an HTTP POST with curl?

Tags: curl, cygwin, http-post, google-search-appliance

I am attempting to access the Google Search Appliance API: http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/612/gdata/acapi_protocol.html

In order to send the requests, I am using curl.  My problem is that when I attempt to login, using

```
curl -k -X POST https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8443/accounts/ClientLogin&Email=username&Passwd=password
```

I get the following:

```
'Email' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Passwd: unknown user =password
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I am new to curl, so I realize I am probably using it wrong.

I have curl installed through cygwin on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to do something along the lines of

```
curl -k -X POST https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8443/accounts/ClientLogin -d Email=username -d Passwd=passwd
```

For a list of command options see
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing your URL with `"`. Since you are using `&` and other special bash characters you need to enclosed them in quotes.

It's a bash issue:

```
$ curl -k -X POST "https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8443/accounts/ClientLogin&Email=username&Passwd=password"
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell interprets the & character as the end of a command: you need to put the whole URL in quotes

```
curl -k -X POST "https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8443/accounts/ClientLogin&Email=username&"
```